# html table preview using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a html table and i want to make a preview of that table display in a popup on button click, i have searched internet and found a plugin but it is not appropriate. please guide me how i can preview the table content using jquery or anything else?

LINK i have found:

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

HTML TABLE

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Part</th>
   <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New part</td>
    <td>231134</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New part</td>
    <td>231134</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the table contents on a click or hover and make sure the clone scales to your little hover element.  Here's a really rough cut with jQuery UI.

```
$('table').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $( "#popup" ).dialog({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).html(clone);
        }
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hg9NJ/

Comment: thanks for this great help :) but i have other fields as well on the page like buttons and div but i also want to preview the table